# How to specify a pragma when using babel-cli?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, babel-cli

For `transform-react-jsx` I have to specify a `pragma` but I want to only use babel-cli. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think providing options in `babel-cli` is supported as discussed [here](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4161#issuecomment-372719915). You should use `.babelrc` if you need to configure plugin options.